# Gulp.js process working on dev by not test/prod

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, gulp

I have a gulp.js process using the gulp-phantom plugin that works perfectly on my dev setup, Mac OS X 10.10, however on my test / prod environment (EC2 Amazon Linux) it just doesn't work at all, however it also isn't giving any sort of error message or any other helpful output, the task just starts and finishes again almost straight away:

Dev environment output:

```
$ gulp crawlSite
[17:39:19] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/dev/mysite.co.uk/gulpfile.js
[17:39:19] Starting 'crawlSite'...
[17:40:15] Finished 'crawlSite' after 57 s
```

Test environment output:

```
$ gulp crawlSite
[17:34:27] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/gulpfile.js
[17:34:27] Starting 'crawlSite'...
[17:34:27] Finished 'crawlSite' after 715 ms
```

As you can see on the dev environment the process takes 57 seconds however on test it is only 715 milliseconds and on test it is not creating the files that my phantom script should be creating. My gulp task is very simple:

```
gulp.task('crawlSite', function() {
  return gulp.src("phantom-crawl-website.js")
    .pipe(phantom());
});
```

and my phantom script "phantom-crawl-website.js" file is in the same directory as the gulpfile.js file.

I have check that all the node modules are installed and that PhantomJS is installed globally on the test environment and everything checks out ok. If I run:

```
$ phantomjs phantom-crawl-website.js
```

from the command prompt on the test environment that works fine and it crawls the site and creates the files.

I have tried to use the gulp-phantom options for "debug" however I can never seem to see any output from this. I have tried using gulp-debug as well as follows:

```
gulp.task('crawlSite', function() {
  return gulp.src("phantom-crawl-website.js")
    .pipe(phantom({debug: true}))
    .pipe(debug());
});
```

However all this does is give me the gulp-phantom output filename ("phantom-crawl-website.txt"). I have also tried to write the gulp-phantom output file in the following way:

```
gulp.task('crawlSite', function() {
  return gulp.src("phantom-crawl-website.js")
    .pipe(phantom({debug:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./phantomOutput/"));
});
```

But all I get from this is a blank file created in the "phantomOutput" directory called "phantom-crawl-website.txt".

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong and how I would be able to see the phantomJS debug output so I can work out what the problem is.

Thanks so much in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get some output from the gulp-phantom process by adding the following to the gulp-phantom index.js file:

```
program.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Once this was added I'm now getting the following error message:

```
stderr: Can't open '/dev/stdin'
```

But still no luck actually getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. In the gulp-phantom module there appears to be an error with it using /dev/stdin were phantomjs expecting the phantom filename to be passed. On Mac OS X the /dev/stdin contains the contents of the file but on Linux it is denied permission to read it.

To fix it I removed the line that was pushing '/dev/stdin' into the arguments stack and then added one a bit further down in the "through" function call to pass the full path and filename to the phantomjs process instead.

I will issue a pull request to the gulp-phantom module creator and see if they accept this as fix for the issue.